# Connecting to the Gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I am working with Liferay 7.2. I am using Liferay Developer Studio and Gradle as a build tool.

While creating a new module project after creating of 1-2 new, getting error message in IDE's workspace .log file and new module project is not creating.

**!MESSAGE Synchronize project liferay-workspace failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build. !STACK 0 org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip'.**

In C:\Users\nirav.prajapati.gradle\daemon\4.10.2\daemon-11084.out file following error shows.

> Problem in daemon expiration check java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC
>   overhead limit exceeded FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Problem in daemon expiration check java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
>   heap space Failed to execute
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon$DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck@7f47f3a7.
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space FAILURE: Build failed with
>   an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Failed to notify build listener. Java heap space

I have increased JVM Heap size by double click on IDE's Server.

Even newly created project is not showing into Gradle Task. In Project Explorer it's showing like incomplete project means folder structure are different then exists. Moreover, .projects and .settings file is also not creating in that.

Multiple time I have make fresh configuration like, remove Liferay developer studio, workspace and .gradle folder from C:\User\

After getting this error, I have restarted system and start again liferay developer studio, but **Synchronize Gradle Project with Workspace** progress is taking more than 45 min. to complete the process.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please these properties in gradle.properties file.

org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=500m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8